# Update/Edit records for multiple rows based on particular ID in Postgres after inserting

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have inserted the below into the custom_property table in Postgres. The insert is based on p.pk_pirana, in this case 12128.What I would like to do is to update the record where all the information is correct except, I want to update the value field from "2" to "1"? The pk_custom_property ID for adsl_mode will change for each fk_pirana

```
INSERT INTO custom_property
(pk_custom_property, fk_pirana, key, value,
type, fk_updated_by, updated_date
)
SELECT nextval('seq_pk_custom_property') AS pk_custom_property,
p.pk_pirana AS fk_pirana,
'adsl_mode' AS key,
'2' AS value,
1 AS type,
1 AS fk_updated_by,
now() AS updated_date
FROM pirana p
WHERE p.pk_pirana IN (12128,12435,54643,23453,432436,....continued for 400 more IDs); 

Gets inserted into the table as a row:

 pk_custom_property | fk_pirana |      key      | value | type | fk_updated_by |        updated_date        
--------------------+-----------+---------------+-------+------+---------------+----------------------------
              30947 |     12128 | asad.down |       |    3 |         15367 | 2017-04-22 09:43:50.859

              30949 |     12128 | psdasd    | 0     |    3 |         15367 | 2017-04-22 09:44:38.579
            32555 |     12128 | adsl_mode     | 2     |    1 |             1 | 2017-09-06 07:04:10.416511
```

Comment: `update custom_property set value =1 where fk_pirana = 12128 `?..

Answer (score 0):

```
update custom_property 
   set value =2 
where fk_pirana = 12128,12435,54643,23453,432436,....continued for 400 more IDs)
AND key ='adsl_mode';
```